# Pass json string as helm values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm getting below error on running a helm install while passing value as json string:

```
$ helm install mychart-test mychart -n mft-system -f mychart/custom-values.yaml --set-string .Values.job.pod.env.server_deploy=true --set-string .Values.job.pod.env.server_custom_values=[{"name":"configmap.properties.portVersion", "value":"true"}, {"name":"configmap.properties.storageVersion", "value":"true"}] --dry-run
```

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: expected at most two arguments, unexpected arguments: value:true},, {name:configmap.properties.storageVersion,, value:true}]

I understand this can be eliminated by using `toJson` in the helm chart in env section but I also have other env variable and I'm using `range` to loop over and fetch all values like below:

```
env:
{{- range $name, $value := .Values.job.pod.env }}
- name: {{ quote $name }}
  value: {{ quote $value }}
{{- end }}
```

Please advise how can I make this happen. I'm aware of other threads in SO but they don't suffice my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use --set-json

```
--set-json 'job.pod.env.server_custom_values=[{"name":"configmap.properties.portVersion", "value":"true"}, {"name":"configmap.properties.storageVersion", "value":"true"}]'
```

Adidionaly you don't need to add `.Values` when setting them with --set

Comment: Getting error: `Error: unknown flag: --set-json`. Helm is v3 `$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.6.3", GitCommit:"d506314abfb5d21419df8c7e7e68012379db2354", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.16.5"}`

Comment: Also, can you suggest what is a better way to make chart changes and make it available as json inside the pod ? WIll converting to base64 enc and then decoding inside pod help ?

Comment: To make it available in a pod i would use config map. You can map it as a volume and have it added as a file to your pod.

Comment: My version of helm is `version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.11.3", GitCommit:"323249351482b3bbfc9f5004f65d400aa70f9ae7", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.20.3"}`